# How to fetch data from firestore with immutable.js and redux-actions in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, immutable.js, redux-actions

I'm a beginner of react native. If you give me any advice, it would be helpful and I would appreciate you.

I'm trying to fetch data from `firestore` using `react-native`, `immutable.js`, `react-redux`, `redux-actions` also this codes follow `ducks structure`.
The problem is that I can't get any data from `firestore` because data from `firestore` comes after reducer executed.

Even, I'm not sure if I could put `firestore` fetching method as second parameter of `createAction`.

Here's my code.

---

**shared/index.js**

```javascript
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'

const config = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export const getCategoryNames = () => {
  return db.collection('categories').get();
}
```

---

**store/modules/categoryImgList**

```javascript
import {createAction, handleActions} from 'redux-actions';
import { Map, List } from 'immutable';

// firestore
import * as db from '../../shared';

// Action types
const GET_NAME = 'categoryImgList/GET_NAME';

// action creator
export const getName = createAction(GET_NAME, () => {
  db.getCategoryNames().then(data => {
    const arr = [];

    data.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data().name);
        arr.push(doc.data().name);
    });

    console.log('arr');
    console.log(arr);
  })
}); // none

const initialState = Map({
    name: List()
});

// Reducer
export default handleActions({
    [GET_NAME]: (state, { payload: name }) => {
      console.log(state);
      console.log({name});
      const item = Map({ name });
      return state.update('name', name => name.push(item));
    }
}, initialState);
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The way I typically do it is to dispatch the action after I have retrieved data from firestore. In this case, though, it doesn't look like you do anything with the data after you add it to the array besides log it. You handle the resolution by loading it into the array, but then I believe you would have to return the array or something along those lines. How does is it supposed to get into the payload?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
It supposed to get data as an array, so it would be `[...name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by my self.
I realized I needed `redux-thunk` to get async data.
I installed `redux-thunk` and changed some code as below.

```javascript
import {handleActions} from 'redux-actions';

// firestore
import * as db from '../../shared';

// Action types
const GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING = 'categoryImgList/GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING';
const GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS = 'categoryImgList/GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS';
const GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE = 'categoryImgList/GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE';

// action creator
export const getName = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({type: GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING});
  try {
    const response = await db.getCategoryNames();

    const arr = [];
    response.docs.forEach(res => {
        arr.push(res.id);
    });
    console.log(arr);

    dispatch({type: GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS, payload: arr});
    return arr;
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      dispatch({type: GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE, payload: e});
  }
}

const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  error: false,
  name: []
};

// Reducer
export default handleActions({
  [GET_CATEGORY_NAME_PENDING]: (state) => ({ ...state, fetching: true, error: false }),
  [GET_CATEGORY_NAME_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => ({ ...state, fetching: false, name: action.payload }),
  [GET_CATEGORY_NAME_FAILURE]: (state) => ({ ...state, fetching: false, error: true })
}, initialState);
```